# Coverflow sample code

Tags: android

The requirement is as follows:

1. I have added four tasks T1, T2, T3, T4 and storing the tasks in SQLite with details.
2. I need to display the tasks both in list view and cover view.

I have already implemented the same for list view and have provided the functionality to delete the tasks.

I need to implement the Cover view display of the tasks and also provide the option of editing the task name and delete the task.
If I am deleting the task, how can I rearrange the Cover view display items?

Kindly provide me any link/sample code so that I get the logic for implementing the Cover View.